# How to block certain devices for my hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, call-screening

I want to be able to let certain devices use my hotspot, block others. Is this possible? Or is it possible to block certain Mac ID's?

Device: General Mobile GM 5 Plus d Android One (Something sold probably only in Turkey)
Android v8.0.0

I hope this feature will be added to the newer releases of Android.

Answer (score 0):

When device connects, in menu where set up hotspot option is there, long press the device and click on: block. 
Use the traditional method: set up password

Comment: I don't see connected devices in settings. I had to install 3rd party software to see it. But these 3rd party  applications don't have an option to block clients.

Comment: Enable the hotspot. Connect two devices. Click on notification. Look there for connected devices.

Comment: I see only this: https://photos.app.goo.gl/DXNDY8GWnjavFEsaA. No devices.

Comment: Re: blocking connected devices from notification, this feature might be added by the manufacturer since there's none on AOSP (vanilla Android). It might help to [edit] and mention the device model and Android version.

Comment: @Andrew T. Added the info you requested. Thanks for your interest.